# Javascript web audio rms not reading stream

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I have developed a webpage that listens to the microphone, calculates the root means square (the average loudness) and changes the colour of the `text areas` on the webpage.

I found the [`audio-rms` package](https://github.com/mmckegg/audio-rms), but the example uses an oscillator and I am not sure how to replace it with a microphone stream.

I then found an article on [HTML5 Rocks about capturing audio](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/), and I used some of the code to capture the audio for use in realtime.

I already have some code that is supposed to calculate the `rms` from the stream, but the problem is that the microphone never sends any audio. By using console logs, I have worked out that the code works up line 8, but it does not work by line 11, which happens to be when calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

The code I am using is below and you can view the files on [GitHub](https://github.com/13smith-oliver/13smith-oliver.github.io):

```
+function () {
    var errorCallback = function (e) {
        console.log('Permission Rejected!', e);
    };
    var ctx = new AudioContext()

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        //works here
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function (stream) 
        {
            //Doesn't work here.
            // 2048 sample buffer, 1 channel in, 1 channel out  
            var processor = ctx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1)
            var source
            console.log("processor")
            source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(stream)
            console.log("media element")
            source.connect(processor)
            source.connect(ctx.destination)
            processor.connect(ctx.destination)
            stream.play()
            console.log("stream play")

            // loop through PCM data and calculate average
            // volume for a given 2048 sample buffer
            processor.onaudioprocess = function (evt) {
                var input = evt.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
                  , len = input.length
                  , total = i = 0
                  , rms
                while (i < len) total += Math.abs(input[i++])
                rms = Math.sqrt(total / len)

                console.log(rmsLevel)

                if (rmsLevel > 65) { document.getElementById("TL").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"; }
                else if (rmsLevel > 60 && rmsLevel <= 65) { document.getElementById("L").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 140, 0)"; }
                ...
            }
        }, errorCallback);
    } else {
        alert("Error. :(")
    }
}()


function resetColours() {
    document.getElementById("TL").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(110, 110, 110)";
    document.getElementById("L").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(110, 110, 110)";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got incorrect usage of navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia - you wrote it in the old style of navigator.getUserMedia callbacks, not in the Promise-based way of navigator.MediaDevices.gUM.  Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia.

Instead of

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function (stream) {
    ...
}, errorcallback );
```

You should say

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then( function (stream) {
    ...
}).catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```